# Finding the occurence of a word in a subfolder

Tags: linux, shell, grep, terminal

Hello i'm trying to find all occurrences of a word in a subfolder. While that seems to be easy i want that  for each occurrence we will display the path and the name of the file followed by ' -> Line: ', followed by the number of the line containing this occurrence.

For example :  `example/example/file.png -> Line: 25`

I tried to do : `grep -rnl 'word' subfolder/ |  sed 's/$/ -> Line : /'` But i can't find a way to print the line at the end Heres an example of what i get using this command : ( `example/example/file.png -> Line:` )

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have a look at awk instead of sed

Comment: Maybe `grep -rn 'word' subfolder | awk -F":" '{print $1 " -> " "Line: " $2}'` or using find `find -type f -exec grep -n 'word' {} + | awk -F":" '{print $1 " -> " "Line: " $2}'`

Comment: Thanks a lot `grep -rn 'word' subfolder | awk -F":" '{print $1 " -> " "Line: " $2}' ` worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *`grep -rnl 'word' subfolder/`*, `-n`  conflicts with `-l`. You have to decide whether you want only the file names (`-l`) or all the matches to be printed along with the line number (`-n`).

So assuming you meant the latter, `grep -rn pattern folder/` would print something like:

```
folder/file:4:line with pattern
folder/file:with:colon:12:other pattern line
folder/subfolder:with:colon/file
with
newline:12:pattern again
```

And it should be obvious that there's no way to extract the line number from that.

It can only be done if you can guarantee file paths won't contain `:` nor newline characters. Maybe with something like:

```
grep -rn pattern folder/ |
  LC_ALL=C sed 's/^\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3 -> Line: \2/'
```

To do it reliably regardless of what character or non-character the file paths may contain¹, you'd need:

```
find folder/ -type f -exec awk '
  /pattern/ {
    print FILENAME":"$0" -> Line: "FNR
  }' {} +
```

Which also removes the need for the non-standard and unportable `-r` option of `grep`.

---

<sup>¹ Though possibly less reliably if the directory hierarchy is so deep that file path lengths exceed `PATH_MAX`.</sup>